# Cordova App 'Android permission Cordova plugin' is not showing permission dialog

Tags: cordova, permissions, cordova-plugins, android-6.0-marshmallow

i am attending to use 'imagepicker' plugin for my cordova app to get images from the mobile gallery and use them . i am testing my app on android 6.0 device and this is the problem, marshmallow Android 6.0 require in run-time permission not like the older versions "it is working on older versions" ,but on api 23 or higher when it attend to open gallery it close immediately and the app crashes . when i searched i found that i need permission to do it . so i started to use "Android permission Cordova plugin" and by copying the example they presented in this page : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

which is :

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
permissions.hasPermission(permissions.CAMERA, checkPermissionCallback, null);

function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
  if(!status.hasPermission) {
    var errorCallback = function() {
      console.warn('Camera permission is not turned on');
    }

    permissions.requestPermission(
      permissions.CAMERA,
      function(status) {
        if(!status.hasPermission) errorCallback();
      },
      errorCallback);
  }
}
```

the console always says : 'Camera permission is not turned on' and no permission dialog shows.

then i searched again and found this solved question and it`s answer , so i installed 'cordova-plugin-diagnostic' and tried this code:

```
function requestPermission(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission(function(status){
        switch(status){
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.GRANTED:
                console.log("Permission granted (or already granted) - call the plugin");
                // call SQLite plugin
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.DENIED:
                console.log("Permission denied - ask again");
                alert("Come on user, we really need this. I'll ask again...");
                requestPermission();
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                console.log("Permission permanently denied");
                alert("Well that's it, we're dead Jim");
                navigator.app.exitApp();
                break;
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    }, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.runtimePermission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
}
requestPermission();
```

the app close and no dialog shows too, i think i can`t get what should this plugins do and how can i get the permission to open gallery. if can somebody give me full example to open gallery and pick image with permission it will be great help.

sorry for my English , and thanks for being patient .

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Comment: have you tried uninstalling your app completely and reinstalling it? That might flush out previously denied permissions and give you a fresh start.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the permissions request to show by adding the relevant permissions and feature to platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In config.xml file, try to add

[image]

and then build the app. It will automatically override AndroidManifest.xml file in platforms folder and thus the popup dialog with deny and allow button works fine.

**Kindly see the below link for more reference.**

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue dear . the requesting dialog box did not appear. after some concentration on my code, i found that, var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions is defined in DeviceReady() function and in the other side i was calling checkPermissionCallback() as a callback function which is not in DeviceReady() function so var permissions is not defined in that function (scopes are different). so checkPermissionCallback  have must been defined in DeviceReady() function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin you used, but I was able to use the [cordova-plugin-settings-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-settings-hook) with these kind of entries in my config.xml to address a similar issue:

`<platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" platform="android" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

To use the above settings in your config.xml, you also need to edit the `widget` attribute to include an additional attribute: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

Comment: The issue is that android 6.0 need run-time permission , so how can i request that permission using JavaScript in run-time.

Comment: You should be able to use your image picker plugin without explicitly requesting permission using JavaScript. The permission request will still occur one time on the first usage automatically, based upon the method shown above. You'll still need to add generic error handling to your image picker code to handle if the user denied the request. The error information you get back should indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the android target version to api 23 in cordova config.xml

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

you can proceed to indicate the required permissions in android/androidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

with this setting, you can use any of the android permission plugins for cordova e.g
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

Depending on what you want to achieve, this should solve most or all of your problems

Answer (score 0):

just yesterday I found this same problem and started looking in the documentation of npm (I leave the link: **https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-permission**), but it suits my need to find the solution.

```
        var permissions = plugins.Permission;

        permissions.has('android.permission.CAMERA', function (status) {
          if(!status.has) {
            var errorCallback = function() {
              console.warn('Camera permission is not turned on');
            }

            permissions.request(
              'android.permission.CAMERA',
              function(status) {
                if(!status.has) errorCallback();
              },
              errorCallback);
          }
        }, alert);
```