# No notification to allow android app to use camera

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, vue.js

I'm developping an app with vue-js and cordova. This app use the phone's camera to take some pictures but i don't know how to ask the user to allow my app to use the camera.

I've tried to use cordova-plugin-android-permissions but it didn't make great results.

( cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions )

I set this in my main.js :

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions
permissions.checkPermission(permissions.CAMERA, success, null)

function error () {
  console.warn('Camera permission is not turned on')
}
function success (status) {
  if (!status.checkPermission) {
    permissions.requestPermissions(
      permissions.CAMERA,
      function (status) {
        if (!status.checkPermission) {
          error()
        }
      },
      error)
  }
}
```

I got only a white screen on my app and my build send me this :

```
cordova is not defined
```

I'd like to test to import cordova but i'm not sure about the path of my import.

I'm also not sure if my method is good and if there are other methods to ask for device autorisation.

Comment: If your error is Cordova is not defined, then your issue is not about the camera but your app just does not build properly.

Answer (score 1):

You use cordova in the wrong way.

You have to wait it to load. TO do that, you have to listen to cordovo ready event.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
      const permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
     // Your code here
```

Link: https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions/issues/13

futhermore, you perhapse need to use 'import VueCordova from 'vue-cordova''
I'm not sur about this but it's a track

```
import VueCordova from 'vue-cordova'
...
Vue.use(VueCordova)
```

In data of your component

```
cordova: Vue.cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to add the following lines in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

as shown in this post: 
[Cordova App 'Android permission Cordova plugin' is not showing permission dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371495/cordova-app-android-permission-cordova-plugin-is-not-showing-permission-dialog)

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't seems to work, my app doesn't crash but the pop-up doesn't appear